# How to recursively Copy a remote directory in Python

Tags: python, paramiko

I am  a novice in Python Programming. I am actually to trying to write a simple code ( Not in OOPs) to copy a directory recursively from the remote machine. Something which SCP does. I have tried refering this link  https://gist.github.com/johnfink8/2190472 , However this looks too complicated, whereas I just need to login to remote host using username and password and copy  the required directories. I'm actually trying with following code, where this is only meant for copying files . and Errors with :::

> Copying Files From Remote Node Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "./test.py", line 34, in 
>       SCP(host,username,password)   File "./test.py", line 31, in SCP
>       sftp.get(sourcepath,destinationpath)   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko/sftp_client.py", line 719,
>   in get
>       with open(localpath, 'wb') as fl: IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/etc'

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import paramiko



nbytes = 4096
host = '192.168.1.10'
port = 22
username = 'root'
password = 'root'
sourcepath = '/opt'
destinationpath = '/etc'


def SCP(host,username,password):
        scp = paramiko.Transport((host,port))
        scp.connect(username=username,password=password)
        sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(scp)
        sftp.get(sourcepath,destinationpath)

print ("Copying Files From Remote Node")
SCP(host,username,password)
```

Thanks
Amit

Comment: What about this https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rsync.py is a simple script with folder copy.

Comment: Can this be used in Linux Box as both source and destination hosts are of linux.  It looks to be importing "win32file" ?

Comment: The specific issue in this case seems to be that it can only copy files and there's nothing to prevent directories to be passed to it.